# Initialize vector using vec! macro and fill it with values from existing array

Tags: vector, rust

How can I initialize new Vector using the `vec!` macro and automatically fill it up with values from an existing array? Here's the code example:

```rust
let a = [10, 20, 30, 40]; // a plain array
let v = vec![??];       // TODO: declare your vector here with the macro for vectors
```

What can I fill in (syntax wise) instead of the `???` characters?

Comment: `Vec` implements [`From<[T; N]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From%3C%5BT%3B%20N%5D%3E).

Comment: @ネロク thanks for your comment, but since I am very new to the language, I have no idea what it means. Could you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: You don't need the macro. `let v = a.to_vec();`

Comment: @AdamComer thanks, however the example in rustlings implies that you should use the vec! macro (and I would like to learn it as well)

Comment: According to the stdlib [vec docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html), the `vec![]` can't create a new Vec from a Slice.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm asking how to use it. I would like to initilize a new vector using this macro. This new vector should copy into itself the same values as the `a` array. (I'm coming from c# background where there are no macros, so there is a possibility that I have poor understanding of macros)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [`Vec<T>` impls `From<[T; N]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From%3C%5BT%3B%20N%5D%3E), it can be created from an array by using the [`From::from()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from) method or the [`Into::into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into) method:

```rust
let v = Vec::from(a);
// Or
let v: Vec<_> = a.into(); // Sometimes you can get rid of the type annoation if the compiler can infer it
```

The `vec![]` macro is not intended for that; it is intended for creating `Vec`s from scratch, like array literals. Instead of creating an array and converting it, you could use the `vec![]` macro:

```rust
let v = vec![10, 20, 30, 40];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `to_vec` method:

```rust
let a = [10, 20, 30, 40]; // a plain array
let v = a.to_vec();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5df888aabd110e8751397f6ebe0c443f)

A per the comments, notice that it clones the elements, so the vector items should implement `Clone`.

Comment: While it works, it clones the element, meaning redundant copies + a `T: Clone` requirement. This is because this methods operates on slices, and not arrays.

Comment: Nice point, let me add that information as part of the answer though.

Comment: What is the difference between the  `a.to_vec()` and `Vec::from(a)`? To be exact, why does it matter that the `a.to_vec` clones the element?

Comment: @TDiblik, it do matters, if instead of creating a copy (as here) of the items you just transform (take ownership) of the underlaying memmory from the original array, usually is more efficient (Imagine a huuuge array, it is always easier not to spend resources on copying it).

Comment: Oh, ok, and if I take ownership of the underlying data, will I be able to use the `a` variable again (for example return it from function and push some new data to it)?

Comment: @TDiblik, no, you will not be able to use `a` again. `From/Into` takes ownership of it (`self`). If you need to have both is better to use `to_vec`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's exactlly what I needed to hear! You guys have been so helpfull btw <3

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to rust.

I think the question comes from [rustlings / exercises / vecs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/vecs/vecs1.rs) that help understand basic syntax for rust.

```
fn array_and_vec() -> ([i32; 4], Vec<i32>) {
    let a = [10, 20, 30, 40]; // a plain array
    let v = // TODO: declare your vector here with the macro for vectors

    (a, v)
}
```

When I try to solve the problem, I searched whether there is a way to enumerate all element in the existing array and use it to construct vector by using *vec!* macro.
It is easy to use *Vec::from*. However, it's not macro but a function.
Or the exercise does not make sense?

Comment: I had the same issue and found this post. I think there's a mistake in the rustlings instruction for the exercise. Or maybe it was a tricky way to make one look up for the documentation and search a bit... Anyway, the other answers to this post cover the case very well.